# Web api validation on nullable parameter fails

Tags: validation, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations, action-filter

I am trying to validate very simple method and I am getting The value 'null' is not valid for Nullable`1 error.

```
    [ValidateModel]
    public IEnumerable<SomeData> Get(bool? showExtra = null)
    {
        return this.MockDataManager.ShowData(showExtra);
    }
```

ValidateModel property is:

```
 public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext != null && actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
        }
    }
```

Now, if i call method with /true and /false it works. Also it works if I call method with / but if i call it with /null validation fails and error message The value 'null' is not valid for Nullable`1 appears.
How to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling it with / is the way to go. Calling it for /null is not what you want to do.

Here's what is happening behind the scenes:

```
/false
OK, let's see if I can convert that into a bool. Yes, I can.

/true
OK, let's see if I can convert that into a bool. Yes, I can.

/
OK, let's see if I can convert that into a bool. No, I can't, so use the default
value specified in the method arguments.

/null
OK, let's see if I can convert that into a bool. No, I can't, so throw an
exception.
```

Comment: I thought that this is the way - than you for great explanation!

Comment: No problem. The only other way to do it if you absolutely needed the `/null` segment in your URL would be to change the method argument from `bool?` to `string` and manually parse it into a `bool?` in the method body. The reason is that WebAPI is treating `null` as a value rather than the absence of a value, which is what `null` really is.